# Segmentation fault while traversing a linked list with hash tables

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, radix

I'm trying to create a program that will use hash tables in order to execute Radix sort on an array of integers. My professor told us that we have to insert the integer at the rear of its respective linked list. I'm trying to traverse a particular linked list in order to insert the integer at the end, and it's giving me a segmentation error, which is something that I haven't encountered yet and can't find a fix for.

EDIT: Used debugger already and that's where I get the error from. Running the code normally just makes it exit. Debugger doesn't say anything else other than seg fault

Here is the full program so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class HASH {
    private:
        struct node {
            int info;
            node *next;
        };

        node *H[10];

    public:

        void initHashTable() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                H[i] = nullptr;
            }
        }

        void insert(int x) {
            int index = hashUnit(x);

            node *p;
            node *q = H[index];
            p = new node;
            p->info = x;
            p->next = nullptr;

            
            while (q->next != nullptr) {
            q = q->next;
            }    

            q->next = p;
                                
        }

        int hashUnit(int x) {
            int index = x % 100 % 10;
            return index;
        }

        void display() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                cout << "H1[" << i << "]--->";

                node *p = H[i];
                while (p != NULL) {
                    cout << p->info << "--->";
                    p = p->next;
                }

                cout << "NULL" << endl;
            }
        }

};

int main() {
    int a[9] = {199, 200, 77, 45, 15, 278, 66, 9, 100};

    HASH h;
    h.initHashTable();

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a); i++) {
        h.insert(a[i]);
    }

    h.display();
}
```

I'm getting the error on line 31 and 32 with this loop. I'm not too sure how to go about this. Appreciate any help!

```
while (q->next != nullptr) {
                q = q->next;
            }
```

I've tried adding a check condition outside of the loop:

```
if (q) {
 while (q->next != nullptr) {
  q = q->next;
  }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249285/discussion-on-question-by-dilly-segmentation-fault-while-traversing-a-linked-lis).